# The reference component could not be found - yellow triangle (visual studio 2017)

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-2017, vs-community-edition

There are two projects in my solution. The references in the first one are detected, while the same references in the second one are not detected. Yellow triangles indicates that those references are not found.

[image: Valid XHTML]

Red is my second project, and blue is the reference to the first project.

Both projects are using same target framework 4.6 (checked in the properties)

The first project is compiled successfully.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning solution and rebuilding it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried cleaning and rebuilding solution and projects one by one.

Comment: It is not an unusual mishap for a .NETCore or .NETStandard project, takes time to get the Nuget packages downloaded.  For a plain 4.6 project I'd start worrying about the machine health.  Reboot ought to be first.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, the problem was fixed now. As you mentioned it was not the issue about those references. There was a missing library in Nuget package folder. It is restored now and the problem is solved now.

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan post what you learned as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering to my own question. Be aware that it is not probably the issue from path of the references. There should be some other problems, which in my case was the missing Nuget library in the **package** directory that is referenced in **package.config** file.

You could restore Nuget Package or simply uninstall and reinstall another version of the Nuget library.